# CUPS “Unable to get printer status”

Tags: networking, printing, printer, cups

Recently after a system upgrade I can no longer print from local networked HP printers.

The error message on the CUPS Jobs webpage is

*"Unable to get printer status".*

When not printing, the output of `lpstat -p` is

```
printer sc209a is idle.  enabled since Fri 19 Aug 2016 12:08:37 EDT
Unable to get printer status.
```

The relevant lines in `/var/log/cups/error_log` seem to be

```
D [19/Aug/2016:11:50:00 -0400] [Job 962] Get-Printer-Attributes: server-error-internal-error (Connection reset by peer)
D [19/Aug/2016:11:50:00 -0400] [Job 962] Get-Printer-Attributes returned server-error-internal-error.
E [19/Aug/2016:11:50:00 -0400] [Job 962] Unable to get printer status.
```

Any ideas how I can solve this problem? Let me know if you need more information. Thanks.